# Vuetify v-data-table , how to render header text in HTML?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#introduction) suggests to pass an `object` array for headers that has a `text` attribute like so:

```
[{
    text: string;
    value: string;
    align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
    sortable: boolean;
    class: string[] | string;
    width: string;
}]
```

But if you pass:

```
[{
    text: string = "<div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div>;
    value: string;
    align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
    sortable: boolean;
    class: string[] | string;
    width: string;
}]
```

It won't render the HTML (it'll escape the text).

So, how do I render **HTML**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [Vuetify example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-headers) of the header slot. It has the means to complete your task.

Below here there is a copy from the exact part, just replace the `{{ header.text }}` usage with Vue's solution using [raw HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) to force HTML string rendering. It will look like something like this `<span v-html="header.text"></span>`.

```
<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <v-checkbox
        :input-value="props.all"
        :indeterminate="props.indeterminate"
        primary
        hide-details
        @click.native="toggleAll"
      ></v-checkbox>
    </th>
    <th
      v-for="header in props.headers"
      :key="header.text"
      :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
      @click="changeSort(header.value)"
    >
      <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
      {{ header.text }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: how to achieve this with vuetify version v-data-table?

Comment: @shashiverma I'll look at it, but it seems that this question must be updated due to broken links that should be pointing at old documentation. Either the question link should be updated to support only old versions or the question itself could be used as a reference both for old and new versions. Thanks for the heads-up! ;D

Answer (score 4):

i found a solution  for your problem:

```
 <template v-slot:item.description="{item}">
   <div v-html="item.description"></div>
 </template>
```

Just replace description with your attribute in your object :

Object:

[And here the image of the object data-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeSh5.png)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the `headers` template slot instead of passing them as a prop:

```
  <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
    <th><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></th>
  </template>
```

Comment: Well this works, but I got a "'props' is defined but never used."

Answer (score 2):

Something to note if you're on an updated version is that

```
<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
<th><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></th>
```

is now

```
<template slot="header" slot-scope="props">
<th><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></th>
```

The version i'm testing in is v2.2.8 but it was probably changed in v2